# Update tqdm bar

Tags: python, tqdm, pafy

I'm creating a small script for me to download youtube videos sounds.
Everytime you download a sound i use a tqdm bar to display download infos.

The first time you download everything work fine, but the second time my bar is completely destroyed :(. i really don't know what's happening with it...

(i think the bar doesn't update correctly)

Here's the code that handle the bar and download the sound

Thanks for your time :)

```
def DownloadAudioFromUrl(url):
    print("Getting the URL...")
    vid = pafy.new(url)
    print("Done")

    print("Getting best quality...")
    stream = vid.getbestaudio()
    fileSize = stream.get_filesize()
    print("Done")

    print("Downloading: " + vid.title + " ...")
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=fileSize, unit_scale=True, unit='B', initial=0) as pbar:
        stream.download("Download/", quiet=True, callback=lambda _, received, *args: UpdateBar(pbar, received))
    print("Done")

    ResetProgressBar(pbar)

    WebmToMp3()

def ResetProgressBar(bar):
    bar.reset()
    bar.clear()
    bar.close()
    # i used these last time i tried i don't undersand how they work :/

def UpdateBar(pbar, current_received):
    global previous_received

    diff = current_received - previous_received
    pbar.update(diff)
    previous_received = current_received
```

So i tried to update the bar with "reset" "clear" and "stop" but it changed nothing